# What is the advantage of using a 1d image over a 1d buffer?

Tags: opencl

I understand that in 2d, images are cached in x and y directions.

But in 1d, why would you want to use an image? Is the memory used
for images faster than memory used for buffers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1D Image stays the image, so it has all advantages that Image has against Buffer. That is:

1. Image IO operations are usually well-cached.
2. Samplers can be used, which gives benefits like computationally cheap interpolation, hardware-resolved out-ouf-bound access, etc.

Though, you should remember that Image has some constraints in comparison to regular Buffer:

1. Single Image can be used either for reading or for writing within one kernel.
2. You can't use `vloadN` / `vstoreN` operations, which can handle up to 16 values per call. Your best option is `read_imageX` & `write_imageX` functions, which can load / store up to 4 values per one call. That can be serious issue on GPU, with vector architecture.
3. If you are not using 4-component format, usually, you are loosing part of performance as many functions process samples from color planes simultaneously. So, payload is decreasing.

If we talk about GPU, different parts of hardware are involved into processing of Images & Buffers, so it's difficult to draw up, how one is better than another. Carefull benchmarking & algorithm optimizations are needed.

Comment: Thanks, Roman.  Does vload16 have perf advantage over 2 vload8 calls? Because I would think it wouldn't, because there is caching after the first vload8 call.

Comment: That heavily depends on hardware architecture. E. g. if your's device native vector width is 128 bit, then loading & processing 16 chars is perfect match.

Comment: Thanks. In my case, each channel is either 16 bit signed int or float. So, the read_imageX will pull in either 128 or 256 bits of data. Now, one of these channels is wasted, because I am not using the alpha channel. But, coupled with hardware out of bound resolution and good caching, I think image will be faster. I will be finding out soon!  Thanks again.

Comment: Roman - I could make you a very rich man :) I have a lot of opencl questions. Just keep answering